# sharepoint migration eror code 0x2040012

Tags: migration

I would be really happy if you could help m e. I took on a project to move fileshare to SharePoint at work . The plan is to have one site and different libraries for each deparment . 
So too see i wanted to migrate IT deparment files size of 43GB. I am running the sharepoint migration tool on the server . Last night before i went to home i started to migration and this morning i have seen this error message.

Would anyone know why ? We have like 2 terabyte space on Sharepoint

[image: This is the error picture]

Comment: Check if the destination site does not have any storage limit. You can find it in https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com or in the site collection itself in storage metrics /_layouts/15/storman.aspx

Comment: Is there any files whose size are almost greater than 2 GB or more? If Yes, this tool has limited capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a year old, but the issue isn't with your tenant, it's where the temp files are stashed when SPMT scans and then uploads:
%appData%\Microsoft\MigrationToolStorage

You can change the location in the advanced settings before you start your migration.